# Unable to mount a directory on Google Compute Engine using sshfs

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, sshfs

I am trying to mount a remote filesystem on Google Container Engine. I am following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

Using following sshfs command:

```
sudo sshfs -o sshfs_debug,allow_other <instance-name>.<region>.<project_id>:/home/<user_name> /mnt/gce-container
```

I am getting error:

```
SSHFS version 2.5
read: Connection reset by peer
```

I referred this link https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh
and  could login using ssh via following command:

```
$gcloud compute config-ssh
$ssh <instance-name>.<region>.<project_id>
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong here? I can't understand what keys and username should I use for sshfs login.

Update(11/5):
I am using following command:

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/google_compute_engine <user>@<ip>:~/  /mnt/gce`
```

I have chowned /mnt/gce folder for my user. I checked the IP matches the entry in ~/.ssh/config file. However I still get the error `read: Connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with command below is that

1) unless you have a static IP, it keeps changing on machine reboot

2) you need to use .pub file

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/google_compute_engine <user>@<ip>:~/  /mnt/gce
```

I finally got it working by following command:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/gce
sudo chown <user> /mnt/gce

sshfs -o  IdentityFile=~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub <user_name>@<instance-name>.<region>.<project_id>:/home/<user_name> /mnt/gce
```

Comment: running sudo chown <user> /mnt/gce made all the difference for me since running sshfs with sudo did not work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few things that might be the cause of the problem:

- Don't use sshfs as root. It's a FUSE filesystem and meant to be user mounted.
- Don't specify a full path as the remote FS. It's SSH, so by default, the $PWD on the remote side is the login user's $HOME.

if ssh works, sshfs will work. The easiest way is to make sure that ~/.ssh/config has an entry for the remote host with the user, port, etc provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this from sshfs

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

maybe help to set file to read only

```
chmod 400 /{{path_to_your_key}}/keypair.pem
```

and connect again.